# git commands in nodejs

Tags: node.js, git, github

I was wandering if someone know/got into a npm package to work with git commands.
I have a nodejs project that I want to do the following commands:

- git clone
- git create branch
- git pull request - from the created brach

I try some npm packages but without any success.
any Help will be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 39):

Using external package: 
You can use [shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs) npm package

Without using external package: leveraging nodejs `child_process` module. Below is the implementation

1.exec_process.js

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var result = function(command, cb){
    var child = exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr){
        if(err != null){
            return cb(new Error(err), null);
        }else if(typeof(stderr) != "string"){
            return cb(new Error(stderr), null);
        }else{
            return cb(null, stdout);
        }
    });
}

exports.result = result;
```

2.temp.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
pwd
git --version
```

3.app.js

```
var execProcess = require("./exec_process.js");
execProcess.result("sh temp.sh", function(err, response){
    if(!err){
        console.log(response);
    }else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

To run the application you can try `node app.js`
Output:

> /root
>   git version 1.8.1.2

Similarly you can add any command in shell script file and run it using node. Demo and source code published in [runnable](http://goo.gl/EZZ7fP).

Suggest checking [git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras) it covers all the use cases of git via commandline.

Answer (score 3):

While [@samarpanda's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237494/samar-panda) answer was helpful, a *slightly* cleaner solution (from the [nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback)) is as follows:

```js
const util = require('node:util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('node:child_process').exec);

async function lsExample() {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls');
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.error('stderr:', stderr);
}
lsExample();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of the modules support PRs, but for cloning / branch management, try `gift`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gift

This module appears to have the most git features. For PRs, I'd suggest creating an issue and/or contributing to this awesome module:

https://github.com/notatestuser/gift/issues

Comment: I'm using gits because my code is too long for comment: [my code](https://gist.github.com/OmerHerera/ae119b391e084297952f). I don't get any error but when checking in the repo the branch doesn't exist. Please note that the repo in the example is only for this example.