# Push Submodules in source control Panel

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a local repository with n number of submodules in it.

sometimes i work on these sub-modules and make changes to it.when i wanted to commit and push these into remote repository what i do is i goes inside of each sub modules and do the commit and push individually which is time consuming and repetitive

What i want is i want to push these sub-modules changes in one click without going through each sub-modules

Is there any way to push all the sub-module changes in single click?

I am using VSCode editor

Answer (score 0):

A [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-recurse-submodules) from the parent repository should be enough:

```
git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
```

If `on-demand` is used, all submodules that changed in the revisions to be pushed will be pushed.

Comment: is it possible to call this git command inside a JavaScript function?

Comment: @asifkareem I suppose so. Would [this work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29655902/6309), using [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs)?

Comment: can you share me the specific codes for push to be used in the shelljs

Comment: @asifkareem possibly `shell.exec(`git push origin ${currentBranch}`);`, as seen in https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/shelljs/exec